# Backbone Model's fetch() does not return an Object needed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My app has a View of bank accounts. When a user clicks an account, full information on this account appears in a pop-up window.
After a click my app opens a pop-up window, sends a GET request to Backbone-Hibernate-MySQL, my Java Controller class tries to return an object, I see the object with all its attributes in Eclipse console, but my app receives an object with only 1 parameter - 'id'. Where is the rest?
Any help highly appreciated.

```
var DetailedInfo = Backbone.View.extend({
baseUrl: 'employee/accounts/',
    el: $("#employeeTemplate"),
    template: _.template($("#showinfotemplate").html()),
    events: {
      "click .btn-success#change_status_btn": "accept",
      "click .btn-danger#cancel": "cancel"
  },
   cancel: function(e) {...},

   accept: function(e) {...},

   render: function(id) {
       var detailedAccount = new Account ( {id: id} );
       detailedAccount.fetch();
       var element = this.template(detailedAccount.toJSON());
       $(this.el).html(element);
       return this;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.template` will be called before `.fetch` detailedAccount data.
`.template` have to wait until fetch succeed.

Try this in render function:

```
var that = this;    
detailedAccount.fetch({success:function(){
    var element = that.template(detailedAccount.toJSON());
    $(that.el).html(element);
});
```

Comment: Edward, thank you very-very much! It works in a proper way now.